# GPO with computer configurations are not applied

Tags: windows, group-policy

server running server 2012 R2 - clients running server 2012 R2 and windows 8.1 pro

I have several GPOs linked to the domain root, some have user configurations only and some have computer configurations only. The problem is that:

1. Settings are not interfered between the GPOs
2. Only GPOs with user configurations are applied when I run `gpresult
   /r` from a test machine!!

I have tried enabling processing loop back and then disabled it, with no results!

I know I am missing something, any help?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you rephrase your question and add more detail?

Comment: If you run the Group Policy Results wizard for this computer in the GPMC does it show this GPO as being denied?

Comment: Are you sure the GPO doesn't apply the computer configuration items?  You need to run gpresult /r with elevated permissions to view the computer policy.

Comment: "*Settings are not **interfered** between the GPOs*" What is the word "interfered" supposed to mean here? Also, have you tried rebooting the computers that are not getting the new GPOs?

Comment: This thing is completely unanswerable as-written. The Real Answer(tm) is "learn how Group Policy works", but that's not a workable answer for this venue.

Answer (score 0):

On a gpo that target computer setting you must be sure that the user is 'authentified user' (its the default there when you create a new gpo).

If you configure a user on the gpo tab, to like narrow down where the gpo apply, then the gpo is now evaluated at the user level.

Be sure the gpo link is enable and enforced.

To fully test do a gpupdate /force and restart the computer

Comment: thank you for the quick answer ..  i am fully aware of those tiny mistakes where user normally falls into , i tried creating a new test gpo and enforced it , and still the only configurations applied are the user's and not computer's !! this is becoming really annoying ! i even tried changing the security filtiring to everyone and adding the test computer name .., still no luck

Comment: If you've removed 'Authenticated Users' from the security filtering then you need to add the computer group / accounts that you wish to apply the GPO.

Comment: @Nawras my answer is that, dont mess with the security filtering, target the correct OU, but dont mess with the filtering!

Comment: not to mess things up , i have created a test gpo and linked it to the domain it self , to bypass any linking issues , the gpo is enforced already and in the security filtiring i have selected authinticated users and the machine name together .. still , only the computer comfigurations are not being applied ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `gpresult` as an administrator:

1. Start
2. Put in search `cmd.exe`
3. Right click on it and select option "Run as administrator"
4. Put administrator credentials into the login box
5. In `CMD` window enter `gpresult /h gpresout.htm`
6. When it's done type `gpresout.htm` in the `CMD.

It should now open GP report in default browser, containing both the users (for the account with which the cmd.exe was launched) and computers GP settings.